# Can I change isolation level in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, transactions, commit, isolation-level

I'm writting a transaction in Oracle.
Can I change isolation level within this transaction for one select statement?
Now I have Read Commit, and I want within transaction change this once to serializable and next back to the read commit.

Best Regards,
Gregory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL, you can use the [SET TRANSACTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SET-TRANSACTION.html#GUID-F11E1E30-5871-48D1-8266-F80A1DF126A1) statement

For example:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;  
set transaction isolation level read committed;
```

Comment: Individual statements within a transaction can't have different isolation levels. A flashback query can allow you to see data at it was at a specific point of time in the past, which may help.

Comment: That's what I want to do:
In transaction with read commit I have select statement. In this select I want to get access to another transaction before commit second transaction.

Comment: @ogrod87 - One transaction can never see the uncommitted work done by another transaction.  That is known as a "dirty read" and Oracle does not support dirty reads.